# Archiving Google Entire Spreadsheet to Folder with no formulas

Tags: javascript

I have a script that archives spreadsheets to a specified folder, but now I need to do this and not copy over the formulations. I would like to copy the values only while keeping the same format. Thanks in Advance!

Here is the script:

```js
function renameDocandarchive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();               
  var docTemplate = "1FhU9Cz7aKKE2WUsyMWl6CklEU4pLjG3mgcywQZXwrVY";
  var docName = "IPT Leader Standard Work";                      
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
  .makeCopy(docName)
  .getId();
  var date = ss.getRange("O4").getValue();

 
  {var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0BwzMebP9AzaiX2VYYW50OWVRcUU");
  var theFile = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).makeCopy(theFolder);
  var oldFileName = theFile.getName();
  var archivedName = oldFileName.slice(5);
  Logger.log('archivedName: ' + archivedName);
  archivedName = docName + (" " +  "(Week of " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date),"CST","MM/dd/yy)"));
  theFile.setName(archivedName);
 //Deletes temporary Document
  DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);}
```

Comment: Maybe you should give a small data example for what you have and what you output. It's not too clear what you are looking for help on.

Comment: The script is shared above, but it duplicates and renames the spreadsheet while keeping all formulas throughout the spreadsheet. I need to do the same, but paste only the values for the whole spreadsheet while keeping the same format. Was trying to figure how to fit {contentsOnly: true} into my script but can not figure it out. Hopefully this clears things up.